Convex combination of distinct measures induced by maps is not induced by a map
I've been trying to solve the following problem and can't seem to make much progress. I tried searching for similar questions but couldn't find any, please let me know if this is a duplicate. Any hints are appreciated.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces and let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$. Given two Borel maps $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ satisfying  $(\text{Id} \times f)_\# \mu \ne (\text{Id} \times g)_\# \mu$, I would like to show that for any $t \in (0,1)$ the measure $\nu_t$ given by
$$\nu_t := t(\text{Id} \times f)_\# \mu + (1-t)(\text{Id} \times g)_\# \mu$$
is not of the form $(Id \times h)_\# \mu$ where $h$ is a Borel map from $X$ to $Y$. Here $\text{Id} \times f$ denotes the map $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$ and $(\text{Id} \times f)_\# \mu$ is the push-forward of $\mu$ under $\text{Id} \times f$. It's also known that $f_\# \mu = g_\# \mu$ but I'm not sure if this is useful here.
I know that if $\nu_t$ is induced by a Borel map $h$, then the change of variables formula
$$ \int_{X \times Y} \varphi \ d\nu_t = \int_X \varphi \circ \text{Id} \times h \ d\mu$$
holds for all bounded Borel maps $\varphi : X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but that's about as far as I've gotten.

Intuitively, if such a function $h$ exists, then the conditional probability on $Y$ given $x\in X$ would be the point mass $\delta_{h(x)}$, but the correct conditional probability is a mixture of two point masses and given by $t \delta_{f(x)}+(1-t)\delta_{g(x)}$.
If $X$ is separable, this argument can be made precise using the uniqueness of disintegrations up to $\mu$-zero sets. You don't need the full strength of the disintegration theorem; you only need the uniqueness part because you already know that an appropriate disintegration exists (which is given as above by $x\mapsto t \delta_{f(x)}+(1-t)\delta_{g(x)}$).
